# DataGridview doesn't store data and shows System.NullReferenceException when filtering

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my application, I get some data from a website and send it to datagridview and after filling data on datagridview, I use following command to search shipping details... i used following command to searh data,,(I **don't use database** to store data)

```
  (DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("ShippingCost like '%"+textBox8.Text + "%;'");
```

here was the way That I sent to data to datagridview.

```
 tabelBindingSource.Add(new Tabel() { Postion = (l + 1).ToString(), Title = title[l], ItemPrice = itemprice[l], ShippingCost = shippingcost[l], NewUserBonus = newuserbonus[l], Rating = productrating[l], SoldAmount = soldamount[l], SellerRating = sellerrating[l] });
```

This is how i created tabelBinding source

```
namespace AliExpress_Search_Bot
{
    class Tabel
    {
        public string Postion { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string SoldAmount { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCost { get; set; }
        public string NewUserBonus { get; set; }
        public string SellerRating { get; set; }


    }
}
```

after the search button click it gave me `System.NullReferenceException` on

```
(DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("ShippingCost like '%"+textBox8.Text + "%;'");
```

[image]

after clicking the search button

[image]

could anybody tell me what is the wrong with this code.. I have been fighting with this for 3 hours.. I couldn't do it yet.

Thank  for your time

Comment: The debugger is telling you that either `DataGridView.DataSource` is null or an object of a type different from `DataTable`. Viewing  `DataGridView.DataSource` in the debugger will show you what it actually is.

Comment: @KlausGütter `datasource` is not null. it filled with data. I think **object of a type different from DataTable** is different.. I have no idea how to fix this.